# Get Values from a valueExpression JSF1.2

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to get the value contained in a value expression. I need to use it for some validation. When I set the value expression in an HTMLOutput it is displayed on the screen. Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
HtmlOutputText output = new HtmlOutputText();
ve = ef.createValueExpression(elCtx, "#{dynamicRow["+ i + "]}", String.class);
//I have tried all options here that I came across.
//Either test1 , test2 , test3 should have the value ve has, but all of them have value "".
String test1 = (String)ve.getValue(elCtx);
String test2 = (String)output.getValue();
Application app = fCtx.getApplication( );
String test3 = (String) app.evaluateExpressionGet(fCtx, "#{dynamicRow["+ i + "]}", String.class);
output.setValueExpression("value", ve);
//the ve gets displayed in the column with correct string values and not ""
column.getChildren().add(output);
// I also tried ValueReference as given in ValueExpression: how to get base Object?
ValueReference valueReference = ve.getValueReference(elCtx);
//an exception is thrown here javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'dynamicRow' resolved to null
Object base = valueReference.getBase();
Object property = valueReference.getProperty();
```

where my table has the following code:

```
FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext elCtx = fCtx.getELContext();
ExpressionFactory ef = fCtx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
HtmlExtendedDataTable dynamicDataTable = new HtmlExtendedDataTable();
HtmlDatascroller datascroller = new HtmlDatascroller();
ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(elCtx,"#{myController.dynamicList}", List.class);
dynamicDataTable.setValueExpression("value", ve);
dynamicDataTable.setVar("dynamicRow");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var` value `dynamicRow` is only in scope when the [table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) places it into scope during processing. This is done by the various `process*` methods on component.

See [`setRowIndex(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#setRowIndex%28int%29) documentation:

> - Save current state information for all descendant components (as described below).
> - Store the new row index, and pass it on to the DataModel associated with this UIData instance.
> - If the new rowIndex value is -1:
>
>   - If the `var` property is not null, remove the corresponding request scope attribute (if any).
>   - Reset the state information for all descendant components (as described below).
> - If the new rowIndex value is not -1:
>
>   - If the `var` property is not null, call getRowData() and expose the resulting data object as a request scope attribute whose key is
>       the var property value.
>   - Reset the state information for all descendant components (as described below).

Comment: could you please suggest some examples? I am new to JSF and haven't done much on it.

Comment: I don't understand why you have any of that code. Why not just look up data on the model?